# Getting data from a json file with arrays

Tags: php, json

I'm having troubles to get specific data from a json file using the built-in php functions.
Let me show you some code :

Json File :

```
{"votes": [ { "date":"November 3rd, 2017 10:08 PM EST", "timestamp":1509743288, "nickname":"Th3ProHack3R", "claimed":"0" }, { "date":"November 3rd, 2017 10:06 PM EST", "timestamp":1509743160, "nickname":"TheKing", "claimed":"0" },  { "date":"November 3rd, 2017 09:45 PM EST", "timestamp":1509741902, "nickname":"some0ne", "claimed":"0" }   ] }
```

My php code :

```
$json= file_get_contents("myfile.json");
$data =  json_decode($json, true);
$voter1 = $data['votes']->nickname;
echo $firstvoter;
```

I had this code working on a very basic json code without arrays. But something is wrong here because I can't get the nicknames of the voters.

I'm just a little bit confused, so what I wanna do is **picking up the nicknames of the voters** and then I'll put them on a table using html.

I hope I get a detailed answer so I can understand some of the confusing stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to get array to json object. hear "votes" is json object so $data['votes'][0] is return first array see code...

```
<?php 

$json= file_get_contents("myfile.json");
$data =  json_decode($json, true);
$voter1 = $data['votes'][0];
$voter2 =$data['votes'][1];
print_r( $voter1);
echo "<br>".$voter1["nickname"];
echo "<br>".$voter2["nickname"];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

After converting into json Decode you array make look like this,

```
Array
(
    [votes] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [date] => November 3rd, 2017 10:08 PM EST
                    [timestamp] => 1509743288
                    [nickname] => Th3ProHack3R
                    [claimed] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [date] => November 3rd, 2017 10:06 PM EST
                    [timestamp] => 1509743160
                    [nickname] => TheKing
                    [claimed] => 0
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [date] => November 3rd, 2017 09:45 PM EST
                    [timestamp] => 1509741902
                    [nickname] => some0ne
                    [claimed] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

In this you need the nickname:

```
foreach ($jsonData['votes'] as $key => $value) {
    echo "Nickname : ". $value['nickname']."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: I see. But your code didn't work for me.
[EDIT: It worked.]

Comment: It's working @whoami but I got another problem should I make another question ?